Issue with debugging in Visual Studio Code for STM32 using Cotex-Debug extension`
I am having trouble with debugging in VSCode. Here is my setup:

Build System: Ninja + CMake + arm-none-eabi-gcc
Debugger Extension: Cortex-Debug
Debugger Server: ST-Link GDB Server
Board: Nucleo-C031C6

I have successfully built the binaries using Ninja and CMake. However, when I attempt to start debugging, GDB exits immediately and does not even launch the ST-Link GDB Server. I suspect there might be an issue with my configuration, but I can't figure out what is wrong.
Debug Console:
Cortex-Debug: VSCode debugger extension version 1.12.1 git(652d042). Usage info: https://github.com/Marus/cortex-debug#usage
"configuration": {
    "name": "ST-Link Debug with Embedded Tools ",
    "executable": "/home/fenil/Documents/code/TI_test/out/build/CustomPreset/TI_Test.elf",
    "cwd": "/home/fenil/Documents/code/TI_test",
    "type": "cortex-debug",
    "device": "STM32C031C6",
    "serverpath": "/opt/st/stm32cubeide_1.14.0/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.stlink-gdb-server.linux64_2.1.100.202310302101/tools/bin/ST-LINK_gdbserver",
    "servertype": "stlink",
    "interface": "swd",
    "gdbTarget": "localhost",
    "request": "launch",
    "runToEntryPoint": "main",
    "cmsisPack": "/home/fenil/Documents/code/TI_test//Keil.STM32C0xx_DFP.1.0.0.pack",
    "svdFile": "/home/fenil/Documents/code/TI_test//STM32C0_svd/STM32C0_svd_V1.1//STM32C031.svd",
    "stm32cubeprogrammer": "/opt/st/stm32cubeide_1.14.0/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.cubeprogrammer.linux64_2.1.100.202311100844/tools/bin/STM32_Programmer_CLI",
    "showDevDebugOutput": "raw",
    "armToolchainPath": "/bin",
    "serverArgs": [
        "-d",
        "-v",
        "-p",
        "61234",
        "-e"
    ],
    "preRestartCommands": [
        "load",
        "enable breakpoint",
        "monitor reset"
    ],
    "__configurationTarget": 6,
    "gdbServerConsolePort": 55878,
    "pvtAvoidPorts": [],
    "chainedConfigurations": {
        "enabled": false
    },
    "debuggerArgs": [],
    "swoConfig": {
        "enabled": false,
        "decoders": [],
        "cpuFrequency": 0,
        "swoFrequency": 0,
        "source": "probe"
    },
    "rttConfig": {
        "enabled": false,
        "decoders": []
    },
    "graphConfig": [],
    "preLaunchCommands": [],
    "postLaunchCommands": [],
    "preAttachCommands": [],
    "postAttachCommands": [],
    "postRestartCommands": [],
    "preResetCommands": [
        "load",
        "enable breakpoint",
        "monitor reset"
    ],
    "postResetCommands": [],
    "toolchainPath": "/bin",
    "toolchainPrefix": "arm-none-eabi",
    "extensionPath": "/home/fenil/.vscode/extensions/marus25.cortex-debug-1.12.1",
    "registerUseNaturalFormat": true,
    "variableUseNaturalFormat": true,
    "pvtVersion": "1.12.1",
    "__sessionId": "1b9b17fc-5d0c-4c46-8558-992eaac6e020",
    "pvtShowDevDebugOutput": "raw"
}
Reading symbols from /bin/arm-none-eabi-objdump --syms -C -h -w /home/fenil/Documents/code/TI_test/out/build/CustomPreset/TI_Test.elf
Reading symbols from /bin/arm-none-eabi-nm --defined-only -S -l -C -p /home/fenil/Documents/code/TI_test/out/build/CustomPreset/TI_Test.elf
Launching GDB: /bin/arm-none-eabi-gdb -q --interpreter=mi2
1-gdb-version

Launch.json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "ST-Link Debug with Embedded Tools ",
            "executable": "${workspaceFolder}/out/build/CustomPreset/TI_Test.elf",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "type": "cortex-debug",
            "device": "STM32C031C6",
            "serverpath": "/opt/st/stm32cubeide_1.14.0/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.stlink-gdb-server.linux64_2.1.100.202310302101/tools/bin/ST-LINK_gdbserver",
            "servertype": "stlink",
            "interface": "swd",
            "gdbTarget": "localhost",
            "request": "launch",
            "runToEntryPoint": "main",
            "cmsisPack": "${workspaceFolder}//Keil.STM32C0xx_DFP.1.0.0.pack",
            "svdFile": "${workspaceFolder}//STM32C0_svd/STM32C0_svd_V1.1//STM32C031.svd",
            "stm32cubeprogrammer": "/opt/st/stm32cubeide_1.14.0/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.cubeprogrammer.linux64_2.1.100.202311100844/tools/bin/STM32_Programmer_CLI",
            "showDevDebugOutput": "raw",
            "armToolchainPath": "/bin",
            "serverArgs": [
                "-d",
                "-v",
                "-p",
                "61234",
                "-e"
            ],
            "preRestartCommands": [
                "load",
                "enable breakpoint",
                "monitor reset"
            ],
        }
    ]
}

CMakeLists.txt
make_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)
set(CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_TARGET_TYPE STATIC_LIBRARY)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD                11)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD_REQUIRED       ON)
set(CMAKE_C_EXTENSIONS              ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD              20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED     ON)

project(TI_Test LANGUAGES C CXX ASM)
add_executable(TI_Test.elf )

# Compiler optimization flags
target_compile_features(TI_Test.elf PRIVATE cxx_std_20)
target_compile_options(TI_Test.elf PRIVATE -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)
target_compile_options(TI_Test.elf PRIVATE -mcpu=cortex-m0plus -mthumb -mfloat-abi=soft -g3 -ggdb)
target_compile_options(TI_Test.elf PRIVATE -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions)
target_compile_options(TI_Test.elf PRIVATE -specs=nosys.specs)
target_compile_options(TI_Test.elf PRIVATE -specs=nano.specs )
target_compile_options(TI_Test.elf PRIVATE -O0)  # Enable size optimization
#target_compile_options(TI_Test.elf PRIVATE -flto)  # Enable link-time optimization



target_compile_definitions(TI_Test.elf PRIVATE STM32C031xx)
target_compile_definitions(TI_Test.elf PRIVATE DEBUG)

# Linker optimization flags
target_link_options(TI_Test.elf PRIVATE -T${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/STM32C031C6TX_FLASH.ld)
target_link_options(TI_Test.elf PRIVATE -Wl,--print-memory-usage)
target_link_options(TI_Test.elf PRIVATE -Wl,--print-gc-sections)
target_link_options(TI_Test.elf PRIVATE -Wl,--entry=Reset_Handler)
target_link_options(TI_Test.elf PRIVATE -specs=nano.specs )
target_link_options(TI_Test.elf PRIVATE -specs=nosys.specs)
target_link_options(TI_Test.elf PRIVATE -Wl,--strip-all)  # Strip all symbols
target_link_options(TI_Test.elf PRIVATE -Wl,--gc-sections)  # Garbage collect unused sections
#target_link_options(TI_Test.elf PRIVATE -flto)  # Enable link-time optimization


target_sources(TI_Test.elf PRIVATE
    ./main.cpp
    mcu-stm32/bsp/Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32C0xx/Source/Templates/system_stm32c0xx.c
    mcu-stm32/bsp/Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32C0xx/Source/Templates/gcc/startup_stm32c031xx.s
)

target_include_directories(TI_Test.elf PRIVATE
    mcu-stm32/bsp/Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32C0xx/Include
    mcu-stm32/bsp/Drivers/CMSIS/Include
    mcu-stm32/bsp/Drivers/STM32C0xx_HAL_Driver/Inc
    mcu-stm32/bsp/Inc
)


# Generate .map file
set_target_properties(TI_Test.elf PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "-Wl,-Map=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/TI_Test.map")

# Generate .hex file
add_custom_command(TARGET TI_Test.elf POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_OBJCOPY} -O ihex $<TARGET_FILE:TI_Test.elf> ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/TI_Test.hex
    COMMENT "Generating .hex file"
)

# Generate .bin file
add_custom_command(TARGET TI_Test.elf POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_OBJCOPY} -O binary $<TARGET_FILE:TI_Test.elf> ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/TI_Test.bin
    COMMENT "Generating .bin file"
)

# Generate .lst file
add_custom_command(TARGET TI_Test.elf POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_OBJDUMP} -S $<TARGET_FILE:TI_Test.elf> > ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/TI_Test.lst
    COMMENT "Generating .lst file"
)

I have used CubeIDE to debug the same Nucleo-C031C6 board, and it works perfectly without any issues.
